# Regex in Javascript using OR

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex expression to match multiple characters such as , OR . OR : OR ( OR )

I have this

```
removePunctuation = /\.$|\,$|\:|\(|\)/;
word = rawList[j].replace(removePunctuation,"")
```

I just want to remove periods & commas at the end of the sentence but all instances of ( ) :

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to look into [character sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the "g" qualifier if you want to remove *all* the punctuation.

```
removePunctuation = /\.$|\,$|\:|\(|\)/g;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with something like this:

```
/[.,]+$|[:()]+/g
```

It'll match periods and commas at the end of a sentence, and brackets and colons everywhere.